# Making top and bottom vertical alignment coexist on the same page - MS Word 2010

Tags: ms-word, vertical-alignment

I'm writing the last page of a report, where there are three short chapters: Conclusions, Acknowledgments and References. Now everything is top aligned, as per default. However, I'd like the last two chapters to be bottom aligned, without having to press Enter repeatedly to create myself the white space. I experimented with the Page Layout dialog and inserted a section break after the Conclusions, but the bottom alignment starts from the following page.

Is it even achievable what I have in mind? And if so, how?

At https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIr3Q.png there's the end results I'm trying to obtain. I created "artificially" the blank space between "dui." and "Acknowledgments" by pressing Enter four times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can

- hijack the footnote functionality (ugly but effective) and play with the footnote styles
- insert a text box and position it absolutely (that's what a textbox should be used for) in Word2010 look in Insert ribbon, Text section, Text Icon

Comment: Thank you, I think the text box is the way to go. I aligned it to the lower left corner set by the page margins and everything looks good.